# Accumulate data in receive buffer in order to prevent busy-waiting when epoll_waiting on slow connections

Tags: c, sockets, epoll

Clients sending sufficient large amount of data with sufficient slow internet connection are causing me to busy-wait in a classic non-blocking server-client setup in C with sockets.

The busy-waiting is caused in detail by this procedure

1. I install `EPOLLIN` for client, (monitor for receiving data)
2. client sends data.
3. `epoll_wait` signalizes me there is data to be read (`EPOLLIN`)
4. coroutine is being resumed, data is being consumed, more data is needed in order to finish this client. `EWOULDBLOCK` and BACK TO 1.

This above procedure is being repeated for minutes (due to the slow internet connection and large data). It's basically just a useless hopping around without doing anything meaningful other than consuming cpu time. Additionally it's kind of killing the purpose of `epoll_wait`.

So, I wanted to avoid this busy-waiting by some mechanism which does accumulate the data in receive buffer until either a minimum size has been reached or a maximal timeout has passed since the first byte arrived and only then `epoll_wait` should wake me up with `EPOLLIN` for this client.

I first looked into [tcp(7)](https://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp), I was hoping for something like `TCP_CORK` but for the receive buffer, but could not find anything.

Then I looked into [unix(7)](https://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp) and tried to implement it myself via `SIOCINQ` right after step 3. The problem is that I end up busy-waiting again because step 3. is immediately going to return because data is available for read. Alternatively I could deregister the client right after 3., but this would block this specific client until `epoll_wait` returns from a different client.

Is it a stalemate, or is there any solution to the above problem to accumulate data inside receive buffer upon a min size or max time without busy-waiting?

Comment: Is it really using that much CPU time, or is it mostly waiting?  When data is available, how much do you get to read on average each time?

Comment: I see in the logs that it is hopping a lot. Each time there is about 4-8 KiB read available. That is about 1-2 times calling `recv` with buffer size 4096 in bytes. The total length (which I get to know after at most 8 KiB) is approx 30-50 MiB. So that makes >5000 repetitions of the above procedure.

Comment: Hmm. The serial I/O system has had this kind of thing - don't give me available data until the buffer is so full or this much time has elapsed - but I've never seen it for the TCP stack.  How many of these 4 KiB reads are you seeing per second?  This just doesn't feel like a real problem to me, though I do see why it's something you'd like to tune.

Comment: All this takes about 2-5 min. So ~5000 repetitions / 3min ~27 repetions per second. Considering the real problem: Well I'm using proxies (potentially chained) and they are (a) slow and (b) add heavy cryptojacking nowadays to the real thing.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a real problem, but it's your question :-)  What if you added a sleep of 1 second after each non-EOF read before going back to calling epoll: then you'd basically force the OS to buffer more of this and keep your process out of it.  This doesn't really answer the question of how to get the TCP stack to do this, and it does feel super hacky, but it might solve a problem for you.

Comment: I've considered adding a sleep, but I felt like this is not right because I have many concurrent tasks (clients).

Comment: Just to clear things up. So accumulating recv buff is not a common thing? If so I'll just stick to it and won't reinventing the wheel. I was just thinking something like TCP_CORK for send buf, so why not something for recv buff.          SRY nvm you already answered this that you have never seen it for TCP stack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202032/discussion-between-steve-friedl-and-ezegoing).

Comment: What you're already doing is extremely common. The overhead involved is nugatory compared to the processing you will do on the data once it's all received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ezgoing and I chatted at length about this, and I'm convinced this is a non problem (as @user207421 noted as well).

When I first read the question, I thought perhaps they were worried about tiny amounts (say, 16 bytes at a time), and that would have been worth investigating, but once it turns out that it's 4KiB at a time, it's so routine that this is not worth looking into.

Interestingly, the serial I/O module does support this, with a mode that wakes up only after so many characters are available or so much time has passed, but no such thing with the network module.

The only time this would be worth addressing is if there is *actual evidence* that it's impacting the application's responsiveness in a meaningful way, not a hypothetical concern for packet rates.